# Unable to scrape even basic information using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape to basic information from this [website](https://www.zomato.com/pune/delivery?rating_range=4.0-5.0) using selenium. I am using the following piece of code(below). But All I am getting is "Access Denied" in pretty little HTML format. Am I doing something wrong?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests                 # Simpler HTTP requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   # Python package for pulling data out of HTML 

##### Web scraper for infinite scrolling page #####
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"E:\Chromedriver\chromedriver_win32_chrome83\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.zomato.com/pune/delivery?rating_range=4.0-5.0")
time.sleep(2)  # Allow 2 seconds for the web page to open
scroll_pause_time = 1 # You can set your own pause time. My laptop is a bit slow so I use 1 sec
screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")   # get the screen height of the web
i = 1

while True:
    # scroll one screen height each time
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i});".format(screen_height=screen_height, i=i))  
    i += 1
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
    # update scroll height each time after scrolled, as the scroll height can change after we scrolled the page
    scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")  
    # Break the loop when the height we need to scroll to is larger than the total scroll height
    if (screen_height) * i > scroll_height:
        break 

url = 'https://www.zomato.com/pune/delivery?rating_range=4.0-5.0'         
url_text = requests.get(url).text                    # Get the session text for the link
url_soup = BeautifulSoup(url_text, 'html.parser')   # Get data from the HTML
print(url_soup)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting "Access Denied" when querying the website with Python requests.
If you add a *user-agent* to *Python Requests* it will work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


http_headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) FxiOS/13.2b11866 Mobile/16A366 Safari/605.1.15'}
page = requests.get("https://www.zomato.com/pune/delivery?rating_range=4.0-5.0",headers=http_headers, allow_redirects=True, verify=True, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

P.S. You don't need to use *Python Requests* or *BeautifulSoup* with *selenium*

Comment: I had to use selenium and beautiful soup because it is a infinite scrolling website. If you have any better solution please let me know

Comment: I checked the website's scrolling and it isn't infinite, thus you don't need to use beautiful soup.  What's your use case for scraping zomato.com? Do you want all the data or only certain items?

Comment: only certain terms like name, rating

Comment: You can obtain those items with selenium.  So remove the *BeautifulSoup* and *Python requests* from your code.

Comment: Were you ever able to extract the data you needed? If not, let me know, because I wrote some code to extract some of the data elements.